# Wavelength and luminance about LCD monitor

Tags: lcd, rgb

Is there any standard (or product) documentation defining about the value of wavelength and luminance while sending RGB = (255, 0 ,0) to LCD monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such a formula exists:
RGB Luminance value   =   0.3 R + 0.59 G + 0.11 B

#### Background

Human eyes don't detect brightness linearly with color. Basically, we see Green as brighter than Blue. So, the term Luminance was invented, which is brightness adjusted to indicate appropriately what we really see.

[Source](http://www.scantips.com/lumin.html)